# TestFlight: Complete test information is required to submit a build for external testing

Tags: ios, testflight, beta-testing

My app is in internal testing on iTunes Connect, but I cannot promote it to external testing. It tells me that the test information is incomplete.

I have tried all sorts of things, including reading [this doc](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/deva50a6ab41) and [this doc](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devdc42b26b8) on Apple and re-entering all the information again. Playing with the [language specifier](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kbEIQaCpGS0J:https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/22799%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca).

This is maddening, because this exact information worked for a previous build.

[image]

Comment: For future reference, I have an app which doesn't require login and I entered all the required informations but the warning was still showing up, I solved it by checking and unchecking again "Login required" and then saving again, maybe there was an incoherence between the checkbox shown and stored value.

Comment: @CristinaDeRito July 2022 and that's still a bug... thank you so much for your answer, saved me from pulling any more hair out.

Comment: I think apple needs to replace their developers, checking and then unchecking? this is silly. this is not the only silly thing I faced at apple connect website there is too many more bad practicing there

Answer (score 248):

I checked and unchecked "Sign-in required" and Saved and the warning icon finally went away.

Comment: Got to love fixes like this. Shouldn't work but they do!

Comment: what! I wasted a lot of time on this scrolling through page to find what's missing :(

Comment: An hour wasted before reading this solution. This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: @erdomester 2020*

Comment: @Trevor Indeed.

Comment: THIS IS JUST A MASSIVE [curses in Russian]!
Thank you!

Comment: Credits should go to @CristinaDeRito that wrote the same answer as comment to OP's question a day before this answer. Upvoting both answers, but felt like Cristina should be credited!

Comment: UNBELIEVABLE!!! After dealing with the many many Xcode bugs, you still have to deal with this additional bug. Arghh!!

Comment: THANK YOU, 2021 brand new app never had sign-in required and THIS IS THE FIX

Comment: HOW!? ... is this still an issue nearly 4 years later? Thank you for saving me from ripping my hair out. This solution still works. To take it a step further, you can go back and uncheck the sign-in box after saving with it checked previously.

Comment: @DanielSmith I opened the comment box to make exactly this point. Quite astonishing!

Comment: Thank you! This problem is still valid today. Pressing the "Sign-in required" checkbox revealed these fields, marked as having errors. Unchecking the box allowed the error to be cleared.

Comment: August 2021 - the bug is still there.

Comment: I love how this still isn't fixed.

Comment: October 2021 - bug still there. Thank God for stackoverflow or I'd have spent days pulling my hair out over this one.

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING

Comment: November 2021 - I'm still with you my friend.

Comment: Oh for heaven's sake. Yup, this was what I needed to do.

Comment: January 2022 and this is still the solution.

Comment: April 2022, the story continues....

Comment: Still relevant ...

Answer (score 31):

Apple has new requirements for test information. It now requires a phone number, but it didn't a couple of weeks ago.

For the benefit of others, here is the information that was needed to be complete for our app on 2 May 2017.

**Test Information**

- Beta App Description

(We had this only in English (U.S.) Although our app has French versions, we were able to get away without a description in those languages.)

- Feedback Email
- Marketing URL
- Privacy Policy URL

**Beta App Review Information**

- Contact Information (all fields)
- Demo Account

(Our app requires a login. Your mileage may vary.)

We did not have Review Notes or a License Agreement.

Comment: i have added all informations in Test Information section of itunes connect but still it is showing " Complete test information is required to submit a build for external testing."

Comment: @Chandni, you need to fill out the Beta App Review Information too, including *all* the fields in Contact Information.

Comment: Seems strange that feedback email/marketing URL/privacy policy URL are all required. The message for privacy policy says "Privacy policies are recommended…" which implies they're not required… And what if you don't have a marketing URL etc…?

Comment: @shim It does seem strange. I'm reporting on a set of inputs that worked for a particular submission. I don't pretend to know the mind of Apple. Nor do I guarantee the correctness of this answer in the future.

Comment: Also, make sure you Create a group for your External Testers, Add emails and ADD A BUILD to start the process

Answer (score 11):

I had to check `sign-in required` and enter some dummy information. after I saved I went back and unchecked it, saved again; all good.

Comment: That's worked. Thanks.

Comment: That seems to have done it for me, too.  What an annoying bug.  But thank goodness for SO!

Answer (score 10):

In my case all information was filled but still showing error "Complete test information is required to submit for review/external tester".
I checkd, unchecked the sign in required option and saved it. It saved succeessfully :)

Answer (score 0):

Upload via CLI works fine:

```
upload using xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios -f build/ios/ipa/*.ipa --apiKey [key] --apiIssuer [issuer]
```